# How to embed my stopwatch

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, timer, gui-builder

I have made a program in Java through netbeans, in the existing project I want to add a stopwatch. I have the following code of a stopwatch in java but I am unable to determine a way to embed this in my program:

```
//All the imports were written here (I deleted them to make the code clear)   


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Toolkit toolkit;
Timer timer;


public NewJFrame() {


    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new TestPane());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}


public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private JTextField field;
    private JButton button;
    private int tick; 
    private Timer timer;

    public TestPane() {

        field = new JTextField(10);
        field.setEditable(false);
        button = new JButton("Start");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.setEnabled(false);
                tick = 0;
                timer.start();
            }
        });

        timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                field.setText(Integer.toString(++tick));
                if (tick > 4) {
                    timer.stop();
                    button.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        add(field, gbc);
        add(button, gbc);

    }
}




/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */


/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */


    System.out.format("About to schedule task.%n");
    new NewJFrame();
System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");



    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I cannot figure out what is TestPane and how do I do it without Testpane, because in the above code gui elements are made with writing java code but in my program in which i want to embed it, there I have used netbeans GUI builder to do all the GUI elements making.
So how do I embed it?

Comment: You've posted a lot of code and haven't asked a specific question.  You need to narrow down the problem that you are asking StackOverflow to solve for you.  It looks like you're trying to leap into the middle of a problem that you don't understand.  Start with something simple and work your way up to the stopwatch to the point where you can't continue, and then ask again when you have a concrete problem.

Comment: @SimonC I don't know where to start :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Netbeans GUI Builder, the easiest way to embed the stopwatch is the create a `JPanel` form and put the timer code there. Also you can have methods to start, stop, reset the clock in that class. You can then just drag the `JPanel` on to the `JFrame` from from the package explorer, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194357/2587435)

Comment: How can I code a Panel? I dragged and dropped a Swing panel onto the screen but i cannot code it by double clicking it. Where do i add the code then?

Comment: Go to New - Swing Forms -> JPanel form. And just use what you're doing in `TestPane` for that `JPanel` form you created. Then from the package explorer you can just drag that `JPanel` form file onto the design view of the main `JFrame` form, and it will appear.

Comment: I cannot drag and drop it into the main java file

Comment: Drag and drop it onto the actual frame in the design view

Comment: And where do i put the main code which is there in the above code block?

Comment: I would just manually drag an drop the components you need, like the button to stop the timer is you need it, and the label to display the time. Then just put your timer code into the constuctor